# Understanding view layout in Xcode 6 InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6

I'm a bit of an newb with Xcode's InterfaceBuilder, trying to make my Hello World app but I don't understand why my layout of the UI elements in Interface Builder do not match what I see in the simulator.

I created a single view project with a new UIViewController class and a corresponding .xib file (I'm not using a storyboard yet). In the xib file, I placed a TextView and Toolbar onto the main view. I have also set File's owner as my custom UIViewController class and connected view outlet to the File Owner.

Here's how everything looks in interface builder:
[image: Interface builder]

When I launch the app in the simulator for iPhone 5 on iOS 7, I get a different layout than on iPhone 5 on iOS 8 and an all together different screen on iPhone 6 on iOS 8.

Here's what I see for iPhone 5 - iOS 7 (notice the black bar at top & bottom of the screens): 
[image: iPhone 5 - iOS 7]

Here's what I see for iPhone 5 - iOS 8 (the toolbar is missing at the bottom): 
[image: iPhone 5 - iOS 8]

Finally, everything looks right only on iPhone 6 - iOS 8:
[image: iPhone 6 - iOS 8]

How can I setup things so my UI elements appear such that:

1. I don't need to manually place the UITextView's y position at 20
   to account for the status bar.
2. UITextView and UIToolBar are
   placed such that UIToolBar will appear directly below the UITextView
   and they fit whatever window size available on the device?

Can someone point me to a good resource to try understand Interface Builder layouts better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove auto layout and size class.

Use auto resizing to make your screen compatible for all screen size.